# If $X$ is complete, then $A$ is complete if and only if $A$ is closed in $X$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, metric-spaces

I'm doing Problem *III.2.21* from textbook **Analysis I** by Amann.

> [image]

Could you please verify if my proof look fine or contains logical gaps/errors? Any suggestion is greatly appreciated. Thank you so much!

**My attempt:**

(i) Assume $(x_k)$ is a sequence in $A$ that converges to $x \in X$. Then $(x_k)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $X$, so $(x_k)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $A$. Because $A$ is complete, $x \in A$. Hence $A$ is closed in $X$.

(ii)

$\Longrightarrow$: This direction follows from (i).

$\Longleftarrow$: Assume $(x_k)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $A$. Then $(x_k)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $X$. Because $X$ is complete, $(x_k)$ converges to $x \in X$. Because $A$ is closed in $X$, $x \in A$. Hence $A$ is complete.

Comment: Looks fine. It is a good idea to use sequences.

Comment: Thank you so much for your verification @hamam_Abdallah :)))))))))))

Comment: Looks good but for (i) you still need to show that the converse is false in general. That is, find a closed subset $A$ of a metric space $X$ such that $A$ is not complete.